# NSDate how to add different years/month in swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift2, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

In a `UITextField` I enter a date to which is added 43 years and 2 months
I would make sure that up to 01.01.2016 the sum is 43 years 2 months
01/01/2020 from the sum becomes 44 years and 5 months
01/01/2022 from the sum becomes 44 years and 8 months
etc.

This is my code
can someone help me.

```
func upDateField(sender: UIDatePicker){


    inizioTextField.text = dateFormat.stringFromDate(sender.date)


    let currentDate = NSDate()

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "it_IT")

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
    let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    inizioTextField.text = strDate

    let yearsToAdd = 43
    let monthsToAdd = 2


    let newDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    newDateComponents.year = yearsToAdd
    newDateComponents.month = monthsToAdd

    let calculatedDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(newDateComponents, toDate: datePicker.date, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

    let resultDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(calculatedDate!)
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
    anticipoLabel.text =  "se tutto va bene dal \(resultDate) sei in pensione anticipata!"
    anticipoLabel.alpha = 1

}
```

Thanks for your answers
I tried to do but I get this error: Can not convert value of type 'NSDate?' to expected argument type Int
in: case_where calculatedDate <2016

Where am I wrong?
Here is the modified code.

var yearsToAdd = 0
 var monthsToAdd = 0

```
    let newDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    newDateComponents.year = yearsToAdd
    newDateComponents.month = monthsToAdd

    let calculatedDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(newDateComponents, toDate: datePicker.date, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

    switch calculatedDate {
    case _ where calculatedDate < 2016 :
        yearsToAdd = 43
        monthsToAdd = 2

    case _ where calculatedDate < 2020 :
        yearsToAdd = 50
        monthsToAdd = 2

    default:
        break

    }
```

Comment: can you give more clarity ?

Comment: So what's wrong? What behavior did you experience and how does that differ from what you expected?

Comment: As an aside, there's no point in setting `locale` twice. (Frankly, I don't see any purpose in setting the `locale` at all, but rather let it default to whatever locale the user specified in Settings). Nor setting `dateStyle` twice. And even if `dateStyle` was different in the second occurrence, there's no point in setting the `dateStyle` _after_ you've built the string from the date.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add different values based on current year, right? In order to achieve this you'd need something like this :

```
let currentYear = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Year, fromDate: NSDate())

var yearsToAdd = 0
var monthsToAdd = 0

switch currentYear {
    case _ where currentYear < 2016 :
        yearsToAdd = 43
        monthsToAdd = 2
    case _ where currentYear < 2020 :
        // ... and so on
}
```

`case` statements in Swift don't fall through automatically.
Bear in mind, that this is a very naive approach. Google translate says that the string in your code sample says something about "early retirement" - maybe there is a formula in your legislation to calculate the offset?

Comment: There should be spaces there - `case _ where`, not `case_where`. The `_` tells the compiler that you don't care about the value, but rather about the comparison.

Comment: You need to extract the year from the date object, as shown in my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks again, there is no more error
  but now it happens that not from the sum, but the date that imposed
sorry but still I ask your help

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: I enter a date but does the sum
only the entered date
but I have found a mistake in my code
thanks , now works perfectly

Comment: Another question, in this way I add different values based on current year, but I want add different values based on insert date .it's possible?